# Does tx-news work with the workspaces preview?

Tags: typo3, typo3-8.x, typo3-9.x, tx-news, typo3-extensions

Does tx-news extension (v7.3.1) work with the workspaces feature of TYPO3? The documentation at https://docs.typo3.org/p/georgringer/news/7.3/en-us/Misc/MissingKnownErrors/Index.html only mentions known problems with versioning feature.

When a record is created in a preview workspace, can it be previewed correctly?

thanks
s

Answer (score 0):

I tested it and I'm happy to say that news & TYPO3 v9.x work very well with the workspaces feature (see attachment of preview page).[preview of workspace changes with news EXT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lm84e.jpg)